# Nvidia driver problem with 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have just updated to 12.04 but on reboot, I only have one display working and cannot change the resolution on this. I have tried to activate the Nvidia driver but get the following error.....Sorry, the installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

I am e newbie and am a bit lost as to what to do from here.

Any help appreciated...thanks.

Comment: Please open the /var/log/jockey.log file and copy and paste it into paste.ubuntu.com and then put the link here so we can check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am having several problems with my nvidia card on ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10, finally I found a configuration that works (on 12.04).

I will describe the steps to the working configuration I have now.

The solution will be installing the propietary nvidia drivers but from the [X-SWAT PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) repositories.

For doing so open a Terminal (if the graphical interface is not working go with CTRL+ALT+F1 to a pure tty -terminal-), and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*  # Uninstall previously installed nvidia drivers

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get dist-upgrade #OPTIONAL.With this we update other x-org(display) components. 

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And restart the computer `sudo shutdown -r now`.