# Driver for Nvidia GTX650?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, asus

After installing a new Nividia GTX650 graphics card in my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, I am stuck with 640x480 resolution.

This desktop pc is comprised of:

- ASUS M4A78T-E motherboard
- Nividia GTX650 graphics card
- 16GB RAM
- 500GB IDE hard drive and IDE CD RW Drive

I have tried solutions the following solution with no success:

- [Nvidia driver problem with 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127051/nvidia-driver-problem-with-12-04)

Anyone have any ideas that may help?

Comment: I forgot to mention also that I am using AMD Phenom™ II X6 Processor

Answer (score 0):

Have a look under 3rd Party Drivers. The recommended nVidia driver should be listed there. If it is, just enable it.