# Nvidia GeForce GTX650

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, graphics

I have read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225141/driver-for-nvidia-gtx650) but there is no feedback. I've also googled it (maybe with the wrong keywords?) but I couldn't find a recent list of supported graphic cards. I'm building my desktop and I would like to ask anyone who knows or who has this graphic card: does it work or not? If it does, any special instructions to get it working (as I couldn't find any official support for this card)?

I've had a bad history of graphic card support with ATI, I'd like to get it right this time. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, almost every nvidia GPU is supported (I have a gf 635M, works flawlessly).

Based on [this](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia_geforce_gtx650) article, the GTX650 works good with both the binary (proprietary driver) and the open source driver.

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics card should work fine. I'm using a GeForce GT620, which is from the same generation, so it should use the same driver. I can tell you that I get great performance (60+ fps on most games) and really no graphical glitches (I used to get screen tearing, but that was a faulty install). Good luck with your new build!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I marked the other one because of the link :)